# Replacing question marks with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, replace, null

I am trying to replace question marks in my data set with np.nan:

I tried using the following code:

```
df['Workclass'] = [row if row!='?' else np.nan for row in df['Workclass']]
```

And this:

```
df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].map(lambda x: np.nan if x=="?"  else x)
```

And this:

```
df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].replace(to_replace =['?'], value = np.nan, regex = True)
```

But none of these solutions seem to change the frequency of question marks in the column.

[image]

Comment: Murtaza, maybe try this in case there is a space or something extra in columns with that '?':  df['Workclass'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if str(x).find('?')>-1 else x)   It seems like  there might be a data issue maybe

Comment: Can you test `df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].str.strip().map(lambda x: np.nan if x=="?" else x)` ?

Comment: so my solution above working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Workclass'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == '?' else x)
```

and if that works:

```
df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == '?' else x)
```

if your looking for '?' anywhere in a string you can use this:

```
df['Workclass'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if str(x).find('?')>-1 else x)
```

Comment: @jezrael how's it not work, i tested it before answering.

Answer (score 3):

There's a more direct approach:

```py
df.replace('?',np.NaN)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some data related problem, because each your solution should working nice.

So you can test how looks data with `?` in `Workclass` column:

```
print (df.loc[df['Workclass'].str.contains('?', regex=False), 'Workclass'].tolist())
```

Or if numeric with strings:

```
print (df.loc[df['Workclass'].astype(str).str.contains('?', regex=False),
              'Workclass'].tolist())
```

Problem should be some whitespaces, you can try:

```
df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].str.strip().map(lambda x: np.nan if x=="?" else x)
```

Or better:

```
df['Workclass'] = df['Workclass'].mask(df['Workclass'].str.strip() == "?")
```